# Android Activity Transition Order

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

In an activity, I'm trying to make a custom transition between two `Activities`. I want the current `Activity` to shrink towards its to about half its size, then have the x-values perform a scale transformation so it looks as if the `Activity` is rotating in 3-D. Then, after that animation is over, I want the same animation in the exact opposite order to happen on the new `Activity`.

My question is, how can I have a pause in the animation, so that the animation for the entering `Activity` does not start until after the exiting animation has ended? I have to use the `overridePendingTransition` method, so all animations passed must be `int` values from `R.anim`. Otherwise, it would be easy using `AnimationListener`. But I cannot think of a way to do it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've since figured it out, so you can check out the answers!

Comment: Since you found your own answer, move your edit to an answer and then Accept it. This is extremely helpful to yourself and the community. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who is trying to accomplish the same thing, I figured it out. The secret is to use android:startOffset in the XML. The code is as follows:

The exit animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <scale
      android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.8"
      android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.8"
      android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:duration="100" />
  <scale
      android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:duration="150"
      android:startOffset="100" />
</set>
```

The entrance animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <scale
      android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:duration="150"
      android:startOffset="250" />

  <scale
      android:fromXScale="0.8" android:toXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="0.8" android:toYScale="1.0"
      android:pivotX="50%p" android:pivotY="50%p"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:duration="100"
      android:startOffset="400" />
</set>
```

Then the Java code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
```

This creates a smooth, well-timed animation that makes it seem as if the next Activity being created is on the "back" of the current Activity.